# PowerShell shortcut

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a shortcut to run my PowerShell script. This works fine but not when it needs to load the Active directory module. I've searched everywhere, but couldn't find an answer. When adding the line 'import-module' it doesn't work anymore:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit 
>   -command import-module ActiveDirectory "& 'C:\MyScript.ps1' "

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You probably want to add a [`#Requires -Module ActiveDirectory`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847765.aspx) line in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon. At the moment you're trying to execute the literal line

```
import-module ActiveDirectory & 'C:\MyScript.ps1'
```

which makes no sense if you try it interactively. It makes no more sense from the command line.

Try

```
-Command "&{Import-Module ActiveDirectory; & 'C:\MyScript.ps1'}"
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want use ActiveDirectory you can put `import-module ActiveDirectory` command in your `$profile` file.